# CMOS output voltage depending on Vss and Vdd

Tags: voltage, cmos, output

How does output voltage in CMOS depend on Vdd and Vss? As far as I know, it is limited by Vdd when Vss = 0 (ground) but what when Vss is not 0 (for ex. -2.5 V?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CMOS logic gate only sees the difference between its Vdd and Vss pins as the power voltage.  It doesn't know nor care whether you consider those to be +5 V and 0, +7 V and +2 V, or +3 V and -2 V, for example.  The output driver stage either connects the output to Vdd for a logic high or Vss for a logic low.

Comment: I know it is not typical, but my question is about CMOS in an analog circut. Therefore I do not know, if I have Vdd = x and Vss = y, is my output voltage limited by x and y somehow? Do I get it right that it will just be limited by their difference (so |x| - |y| ?)

Comment: By "limited by" I mean it "is no higher than".

Comment: This should be stated in the datasheet for the part you are using.  If the part has a "ground" pin in addition to Vdd and Vss, then I'd expect the output to be limited to ground and Vdd.  With no explicit ground connection, I'd expect the output to swing between Vdd and Vss - but that's only my guess, as I have no idea what parts you are using.

Comment: @Byakuya: "normal" ICs are limited by their power supply pins, they can only produce output voltages between their Vdd & Vss. If Vdd is 5V, Vss is 2V, then the outputs can only be between 2V & 5V.

Comment: @Byakuya: \$V_{SS} \le V_{OUT} \le V_{DD}\$